# Access My Windows 7 Server by External IP from Machine on Local Network

Tags: iis, networking, ip-address, windows-7-x64

I have setup a number services on my home network (two security system DVR's and IIS on my Windows 7 machine).

All of these devices are behind two routers and have static IP's.  I have configured port forwarding on both routers so that everything is accessible via my public IP address.  When querying my public IP address outside from a machine outside of my local networ, everything is 100% accessible and working as expected.  However, when querying my public IP from a machine or device on my local network, the requests just timeout with nothing served.  The only way I can access these resources from a machine on my local network is by querying them by their local IP address.

To explain more clearly (using example IP's):

- My Windows 7 machine (which has IIS setup, accessible over port 80) has a local IP of 192.168.1.100
- My first security system DVR has a local IP of 192.168.1.101 and is accessible over port 5000
- My second security system DVR has a local IP of 192.168.1.102 and is accessible over port 5001

My public (static) IP address is 222.222.222.222

When I am outside of my local network and I open http://222.222.222.222/ in my browser, my Windows 7 IIS website appears in my browser.  When I am outside of my local network and I open http://222.222.222.222:5000/ in my browser, my first security system appears in my browser.  Lastly, when I am outside of my local network and I open http://222.222.222.222:5001/ in my browser, my second security system appears in my browser.

However, when I am on my local network, I am unable to load any of these devices using my external IP address.  The requests just timeout with nothing loaded.  When I am on my local network the only way I can get these to load in my browser is by browsing directly to their local IP addresses in my browser.

I'm guessing that I somehow need to either A: get my request for my public IP when on my local network be first sent outside my local network and then sent back to it through my public IP or B: somehow detect if the public IP address is being queried from a local IP and if so, serve up those resources via their local IP...however I don't know if either of those are correct, and even if they are, I don't know how I'd go about doing it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?  All the machines on my local network I'd like to access these resources from are Windows 7 machines, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you could utilize NAT loopback if your router(s) supports it.  [NAT Loopback Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)

If your routers don't support NAT loopback, you may have to go with option B (better than A).  Assuming you only need this functionality from one PC, you could mess with the routing tables.  That would get really messy in Windows, but possible.  *AND* you would have to track your dynamically changing external IP address somehow. I'll leave options A and B at "improbable" but I'd love for the community to prove me wrong =)